# ggplotly with dynamically adjusted number of bins

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I want to know if the number of bins can be dynamically updated when using ggplotly.

Here is a sample code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

x <- data.frame(a = 1:100, b = sample(rep(1:5,20)))
test <- ggplot(x, aes(a, fill = as.factor(b))) + geom_histogram(bins = 20)
ggplotly(test)
```

For instance, if I zoom in from 1:15, I would want that to split into 15 bars instead of 3 (arbitrary number of bins here).
Would this be possible?